# How to get the child of a element with event.target

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get the child elements of a div to toggle a class 'active'

JS

```
    const dots = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dots]');
    dots.forEach(dot => dot.addEventListener('click', handleClick));

    function handleClick(e) {
     e.target.getElementsByClassName('tb-drop').classList.toggle('active');
     console.log(e.target.getElementsByClassName('tb-drop'))
    }
```

HTML

```
       <div class="dots" data-dots>
         <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v dots"></i>
         <div class="tb-drop">
            <i class="far fa-edit icon-grid"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-link icon-grid"></i>
         </div>
       </div>
```

So i'm selecting all the divs with the data-dots attribute and then select the child of that div and add the class active. I tried with e.target.children but didnt work.

Thanks, I'm just trying to learn :)

Comment: Can you add the html

Comment: Do you want to target all children or just the first?

Comment: "*So [I'm] selecting all the divs with the data-toggle attribute*" - no, you aren't; you're selecting the elements with a `data-dots` attribute; and you haven't specified which child, or all children, you wish to add the 'active' class to. Please understand that this information is all we know in order to try and help you, the more accurately describe your intentions, needs, requirements and relevant limits the more easily we can help you.

Comment: Just the first. The one with the class tb-drop

Comment: But if I'm reading your code right, `tb-drop` is your second element, not your first.  Your first is the `<i>` tag.

Comment: The element with class `tb-drop` is the second child.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right! I just want to add the class active to the children 'tb-drop'

Comment: No, It is not. Remember i'm selecting the div with the data-dots. And from this. I want to select the first child

Comment: If you selected the first child of `data-dots` you would get your `<i>` element.

Comment: You are reading right :D so yeah its the second

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to identify the first child, the easiest option is simply to use `Element.querySelector()` in place of `Element.getElementsByClassName()`:

```
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dots]');
dots.forEach(dot => dot.addEventListener('click', handleClick));

function handleClick(e) {
  // Element.querySelector() returns the first - if any -
  // element matching the supplied CSS selector (element,
  // elements):
  e.target.querySelector('.tb-drop').classList.add('active');
}
```

The problem is, of course, that if no matching element is found by `Element.querySelector()` then it returns `null`; which is where your script will raise an error. So, with that in mind, it makes sense to check that the element exists before you try to modify it:

```
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dots]');
dots.forEach(dot => dot.addEventListener('click', handleClick));

function handleClick(e) {
  let el = e.target.querySelector('.tb-drop');
  if (el) {
    el.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

It's also worth noting that `EventTarget.addEventListener()` passes the `this` element into the function, so rather than using:

```
e.target.querySelector(...)
```

it's entirely possible to simply write:

```
this.querySelector(...)
```

Unless, of course, `handleClick()` is rewritten as an Arrow function.

Demo:

```js
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dots]');
dots.forEach(dot => dot.addEventListener('click', handleClick));

function handleClick(e) {
  let el = e.target.querySelector('.tb-drop');
  if (el) {
    el.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

i {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
}

::before {
  content: attr(class);
}

.active {
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots" data-dots>
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v dots"></i>
  <div class="tb-drop">
    <i class="far fa-edit icon-grid"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-link icon-grid"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, if you wish to toggle the 'active' class you could, instead, use `toggle()` in place of `add`:

```js
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dots]');
dots.forEach(dot => dot.addEventListener('click', handleClick));

function handleClick(e) {
  let el = e.target.querySelector('.tb-drop');
  if (el) {
    el.classList.toggle('active');
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

i {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
}

::before {
  content: attr(class);
}

.active {
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots" data-dots>
  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v dots"></i>
  <div class="tb-drop">
    <i class="far fa-edit icon-grid"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-link icon-grid"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`Element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

Answer (score 1):

`e.target` already *is* the clicked child of the element that you installed the listener on. You probably want to use `e.currentTarget` or `this` instead.
Then you can go using `.getElementsByClassName()`, `.querySelector[All]()` or `.children` from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code.

```
 var dots = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dots]');
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
          handleClick(this);
      }, false);
  }

function handleClick(object) {
     var container = object.getElementsByClassName('tb-drop')[0];
     if (container != undefined) {
        if (container.classList.contains('active')) {
            container.classList.remove('active')
        }else{
            container.classList.add('active')
        } 
     }
}
```